# how can write a cell into csv file

Tags: matlab

I have a cell that contains 4 columns(string-double-double-double).
I want save this cell in a csv file and I wrote this code:

```
fid = fopen('1.csv', 'w') ;
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', mycell{:,1}) ; 
fclose(fid) ;
dlmwrite('1.csv', mycell(:,2:end), '-append') ;
```

but this code write the first column. then write other columns down of first column. but I want 4 columns Place side by side as described above.

this picture is a sample of my data:
[image: sample of data]

Comment: `dlmwrite` when you append **always** writes elements below the current text.  Please show what your cells look like as to achieve what you want depends on your cell array's contents.

Comment: @rayryeng  please see my update

Comment: Do you **have** to write the strings first followed by the numbers? It's possible to do this in one `fprintf` call without having to save the intermediate file first.

Comment: excuse me. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: You are writing the first column first, followed by the numbers after.  Why don't you just write the entire cell array to file? It's possible with one `fprintf` statement.

Comment: @rayryeng  No. It not important that writing the first column first. yes I wrote this code `fprintf(fid, '%s %d %d %d \n', mycell{i,:}) ;` and `i` is 1 to last line. but this code write all columns in just one cell in csv file.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to use a for loop with a single fprintf statement

```
fid = fopen('1.csv', 'w') ;
for i = 1:size(mycell,1)
    fprintf(fid, '"%s",%f,%f,%f\n', mycell{i,:}) ;
end
fclose(fid) ;
```

Note the comma in between the format strings. If you don't place a comma the data will appear as a single column in the csv file.

Comment: In one comment in above post I write that I used this row but this is not correct. because this code write all of values in one cell in csv file and go to next line. for any line this problem is exist.

Comment: I had not seen your comment before but there is a difference between our codes. You said you used `fprintf(fid, '%s %d %d %d \n', mycell{i,:}) ;`. But I used `fprintf(fid, '%s,%d,%d,%d\n', mycell{i,:}) ;`. The difference is that I separated the values with commas, while you separated them with spaces. Standard csv files identify separate columns according to commas, thats why csv stands for comma separated values. In your case there was no comma, thus it was interpreted as a single column.

Comment: I write comma in my code but my problem not solve. still all of value write in one column.

Comment: It must be an issue with the string termination. Maybe enclosing it with double quotes fixes the problem. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write:

```
xlswrite('1.csv',mycell);
```

Comment: @Eli  if this solved your problem. please upvote/accept it. thanks.